# Google Calendar feed format?

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, atom-feed

I am trying to create a calendar feed that is compatible with Google and FullCalendar.

What I find strange is that if you download and save the source of a Google calendar feed to a server it looks fine in the feed reader but no in the Google calendar.

view-source:http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en@holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic

Then saved to:

http://www.knewtv.com/real-estate/floorplans/SFZC_City_Center/googlecal-source.xml

Why won't this display in a Google calendar?

Comment: When I tried adding your version of the XML file, I got an error `Could not fetch the url because robots.txt prevents us from crawling the url.`

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, Google Calendar cannot subscribe to feed in its own format. Your only option for subscribing is iCal (it says so when you click "add by url"). For importing, you can also use CSV.